# How to get more information about the last query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How can we get the host name and the login name of the user that executed the last query in SQL Server, similar to what SQL Server Profiler shows you? The below code gives me only the text and execution time of the last query. I want to additionally return the host name and the user login name.

```
SELECT  deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it with the default trace:

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default) 
SELECT * FROM fn_trace_gettable('xxxxxx.trc', default)
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175513.aspx